# Получить список id, которые отсутствуют в бд

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть таблица, `id` в которой заполняются вручную. Получилось так, что некоторые `id` оказались пропущены. Я могу получить список `id`, которые есть в таблице. Как мне с помощью sql вычислить `id`, которых нет в этом списке?

Comment: Построить последовательность и сравнить с текущими ID, команды построения последовательности могут отсутствовать, это зависит от производителя и версии сервера баз данных

Comment: Укажите DBMS. Без этого возможны только общие советы. Также укажите желаемую форму вывода - один id на запись, или лучше "от-до".

Comment: Дополнил. Диапазон от 1 до 2500. Из этого диапазона необходимо получить список отсутствующих id.

Comment: какая версия mysql?

Comment: Команда SHOW VARIABLES выдаёт: version 10.1.34-MariaDB.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Зачем Вы добавили метку mysql, если ТС указал mariadb?

Comment: @0xdb изначально в тексте было указано mysql

Comment: 0xdb, метку mariadb я позже добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под рукой нет БД этой версии.
Попробуйте этот запрос:

```
SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_2501
left join yourtable on seq=youridcol
where youridcol is null
```

Comment: если верить оф.сайту, работать должно с 10.1 - From MariaDB 10.1, the Sequence engine is installed by default - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/

Comment: А что тут с правками происходит?

Comment: Для MarioDB: 

    SELECT
       s.seq
     FROM seq_1_to_2501 s
       left join `tableid` t on s.seq=t.`id`
     where 
       t.`id` is null
 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=704afd8388177cee1fa02b94b01c9e45

Comment: @2SRTVF спасибо за бдительность:)

Comment: @2SRTVF, спасибо большое. Это типа jpql синтаксиса получается? Если вы понимаете, о чём я... Просто я java изучаю, hibernate.

Comment: У ORM (hibernate, EF) свой синтаксис, у производителей серверов БД тоже синтаксис sql отличается :)

Answer (score 3):

В коде ниже используем 
[sql.ru создать таблицу и заполнить её последовательностью](http://www.sql.ru/forum/965170/sozdat-tablicu-i-zapolnit-eyo-posledovatelnostu)

А в mariaDB последовательность строится одной командой, например

> SELECT * FROM seq_1_to_15_step_2;

также можно посмотреть тут: [Способы генерации числовой последовательности (данных) в MySQL](https://habr.com/post/302926/)
)

> ```
> create table `tableid` (`id` int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into `tableid` (`id`) values
> (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),   (7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),  (14);
> ```

> ```
> select
>    R.`number`
> from
>
>   (
>   select 1000*t4.n + 100*t3.n + 10*t1.n + t2.n + 1 as `number`
>   from 
>   (
>     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
>     union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 ) t1
>     cross join
>     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
>     union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 ) t2
>     cross join
>     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
>     union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3
>     cross join
>     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
>     union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
>     )
>   ) R
>
> left outer join `tableid` t on t.`id` = R.`number`
> where 
>   R.`number` <2501
>   and t.`id` is null
> order by `number`
> ```
>
> ```
> | number |
> | -----: |
> |      6 |
> |     13 |
> |     15 |
> |     16 |
> |     17 |
> |     18 |
> |     19 |
> |     20 |
> |    ... |
> |   2500 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6819cee04366bf11209afbb1934947e4)*

Comment: Спасибо. Это надо переварить. Видимо, мне всё таки проще пока в коде java набросать программку, и заполнить отсутствующие id. :)

Answer (score 0):

Пример для БД не поддерживающей sequence, для первого отсутствующего значения из указанного диапазона:

```
    SELECT (`tbl`.`id`+1) as freeID
    FROM `tbl`
    WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM `tbl` as `st` WHERE `st`.`id` = (`tbl`.`id` + 1)) IS NULL
    AND `tbl`.`id`>=minID AND `tbl`.`id`<=maxID
    ORDER BY `tbl`.`id` LIMIT 1
```

где: minID - минимальный id в искомом диапазоне, maxID - максимальный id в искомом диапазоне.
Единственное условие: значение minID должно присутствовать в таблице, значения id уникальны.