# Пропущенные числа в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с одним полем, заполненным числами, допустим:

**1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 22, 24, 25**.

Нужно создать запрос, результатом которого будет таблица с полем, содержащим те же числа, но что бы пропущенные числа заменялись, например нулём. То есть:

**1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 11, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 24, 25**

Я не слишком хорош в SQL, поэтому, по возможности, предложите не слишком сложное решение.

Comment: Какой сервер баз данных? Поставьте метку. Ранее была близкая тема "Получить список id, которые отсутствуют в бд"

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856965/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-id-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4/856988#856988

Comment: Спасибо, изначально не смог разобраться в примере по ссылке, но Ваш ответ ниже прояснил ситуацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В "With" cоздали последовательность от 1 до 100, 
ограничили ее минимальным и максимальным значением из таблицы datatable.

Соединили последовательность с datatable левым внешним соединением.
в строках, где последовательность не нашла значение num в таблице datatable, 
datatable.num будет null, заменяем null на 0, 
результат вставляем в othertable.

> ```
> create table datatable (num int);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> create table othertable (num int);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> insert into datatable (num) values (1), (2), (3), (5), (7), (11), (12), (13), (22), (24), (25);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> with TblSeq as 
> (
> select 10*t1.n + t2.n + 1 as "num"
>   from 
>   (
>     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
>     union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 ) t1
>     cross join
>     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
>     union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 ) t2
>     ) 
> where 
>    10*t1.n + t2.n + 1 between (select min(num) from datatable) and (select max(num) from datatable)
> )
> insert into othertable (num)
> select 
>   (case when datatable.num is null then 0 else datatable.num end) num
> from TblSeq
>   left outer join datatable on TblSeq.num = datatable.num
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 25 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from othertable
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | num |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> |   2 |
> |   3 |
> |   0 |
> |   5 |
> |   0 |
> |   7 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |  11 |
> |  12 |
> |  13 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |   0 |
> |  22 |
> |   0 |
> |  24 |
> |  25 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53cd63fe9223f1b0377248337d34a874)*

Comment: Спасибо. Изначально думал, что нужно сделать поле с последовательностью от 1 до max (val) и сравнивать значения из этого поля со значениями из начального поля, но не знал, как сделать нужное количество записей в таблице. Ваш пример помог.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
maxmin (vmin, vmax) AS
(SELECT MIN(num), MAX(num) 
 FROM datatable
),
temp (num) AS
(SELECT vmin FROM maxmin
 UNION ALL
 SELECT num+1 FROM temp WHERE num < (SELECT vmax FROM maxmin)
)
INSERT INTO othertable (num)
SELECT COALESCE(datatable.num, 0)
FROM temp
LEFT JOIN datatable ON temp.num = datatable.num
```

`datatable` - имя исходной таблицы, `num` - имя поля с числами в ней.

`othertable` - заполняемая таблица, `num` - имя поля с числами в ней.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93530f07d03b6e14f6670cd9954fc24d)

Answer (score 0):

Если задача одноразовая - перенести данные из одной таблицы в другую с некоторыми изменениями, то наиболее простое решение - использовать [курсор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
DECLARE @counter INT= 1, @number INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT st.Number
    FROM source_table AS st
    ORDER BY st.Number;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @number;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        WHILE @number > @counter
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO target_table(Number) VALUES(0);
                SET @counter+=1;
            END;
        INSERT INTO target_table(Number) VALUES(@number);
        SET @counter+=1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @number;
    END;
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Где `source_table` - исходная таблица, а `target_table` - искомая. Имя числового поля в обеих таблицах - `Number`.